# Layouts content not updating in Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, onresume

I am using `ViewPager` inside `An Activity`  and the `Fragment` that I am using as `page` is not being updated.

Problem : The data in `log` are working in fine but the `layouts` are not being updated but they do change if I swipe the viewpager in opposite direction to that of current direction I am swiping.

Inside the `onResume` of `Fragment` I have used the following code :

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        args = getArguments();
        currentDTO= (CalendarDto) data.get(args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT)) ;
        Log.i("datatest","data position:"+args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT));
        Log.i("datatest","day: "+currentDTO.getDayId());

        setDataInLayout();
    }



    private void setDataInLayout() {


         sunrise.setText( currentDTO.getSunrise() + "");
         sunset.setText( currentDTO.getSunset() + "");         
        Log.i("datatest","data setting complete");


    }
```

**Update :**

I think the problem is with viewpager because :

1. When I am swiping in to left then I suddenly swipe right then the layout is updated unlike swiping continuously in same direction.
2. When I swipe to left and get the position of data (args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT))  which I am sending to fragment from activity in bundle and then suddenly swipe right then the index of the viewpager changed by 3.

Comment: may be existing showing data is same as new data.

Comment: i dont think so but let me check :)

Comment: No it is not the same datain currentDTO are being updated and they are also updated in log but not in layout. they do change only when i change the direction of swipe in view pager

Comment: in logs check this value currentDTO.getSunrise()

Comment: already did and its working fine